# C# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel with tls1.3

Tags: c#, webrequest

We are unable to connect to an HTTPS server using `WebRequest` because of this error message:

`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

i use this code on net framwwork 4.8, website use tls 1.3

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11| 
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12| 
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
            WebRequest.Create("https://manga1001.com/").GetResponse();
```

Comment: https://manga1001.com/ is not reachable. Thats the reason why.

Comment: maybe it block your ip https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmanga1001.com

Comment: Have you enabled TLS 1.3 in your registry? See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210166/2791540)

Comment: What version of VS are you using?  I tried same thing last week and it failed with old version of VS.  Then tried 12288  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netcore-3.1) Then used sniffer to verify the version of TLS that was being used.  After some research VS doesn't support TLS 1.3.  Removed the TLS and tried using the default window version (will vary with version of Windows) and that also failed.

Comment: Fiddler says it's using TLS 1.2: *A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)*