# C# tls1.3 Exception: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received

Tags: c#, ssl

I want to test tls1.3, so i created a console app in VS 2019(Version 16.7.7) and the target framework is .NET Core 3.1.
[image]

My Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSsl {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SslProtocols protocol = SslProtocols.Tls13;
            Console.WriteLine($"testing SslProtocols.{protocol}");
            int port = 1999;
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
                return (true);
            };
            X509Certificate2 serverCert = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "testpass123");
            X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx", "testpass123");
            TcpListener server = TcpListener.Create(port);
            server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            server.Server.NoDelay = true;
            server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
            server.Start();
            Task taskServer = Task.Run(() => {
                TcpClient romoteClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Task.Run(() => {
                    using(romoteClient) {
                        using(SslStream sslStreamRomoteClient = new SslStream(romoteClient.GetStream(), false, certificateValidationCallback)) {
                            try {
                                sslStreamRomoteClient.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCert, true, protocol, true);
                                byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
                                int len = sslStreamRomoteClient.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                string receive = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, len);
                                Console.WriteLine($"server receive:{receive}");
                                sslStreamRomoteClient.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ok"));
                                Console.WriteLine($"server send:Ok");
                            } catch(Exception ex) {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).Wait();
            });
            Task taskClient = Task.Run(() => {
                try {
                    using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient()) {
                        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);
                        using(SslStream sslStreamClient = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, certificateValidationCallback)) {
                            sslStreamClient.AuthenticateAsClient("127.0.0.1", new X509CertificateCollection() { clientCert }, protocol, true);
                            string send = "hi, i am testing tls";
                            sslStreamClient.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(send));
                            Console.WriteLine($"client send:{send}");
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
                            int len = sslStreamClient.Read(buf);
                            string receive = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, len);
                            Console.WriteLine($"client receive:{receive}");
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            });
            Task.WaitAll(taskClient, taskServer);
        }
    }
}
```

And then according to [how to enable TLS 1.3 in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072561/how-to-enable-tls-1-3-in-windows-10/59210166#59210166) i enabled TLS 1.3 in regedit.
[image: TLS1.3 client]

[image: TLS1.3 server]

My PC information:

[image]

Then i debug my project and met a exception

[image]

The debug console:

[image]

Are there any requirements for these pfx certificate?

How can solve this exception? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant code in full, a clear question, bunch of version info and pictures - Questions like i love to see them!

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem, but I was running into similar issues locally with the same setup, I don't think that TLS 1.3 in SChannel is production ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the max version of windows 10 is version 20H2([OS Build 19042.630](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4586781/windows-10-update-kb4586781)). The TLS1.3 server works well only when [TLS1.3 server is enabled in regedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072561/how-to-enable-tls-1-3-in-windows-10/59210166#59210166). But TLS1.3 client does not work even [TLS1.3 client is enabled in regedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072561/how-to-enable-tls-1-3-in-windows-10/59210166#59210166). At the moment TLS1.3 client only works in [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 20170](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/07/15/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20170/).