# Has anyone tried using TLS 1.3 using SChannel with Windows-11 21h2?

Tags: c++, tls1.3, windows-11, schannel

I'm working on a TLS client that needs to be upgraded to use TLS 1.3 on Windows-11. Has anyone successfully implemented TLS 1.3 using SChannel APIs?

As per Microsoft below link TLS 1.3 is supported in win-11 & server-2022

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

below code snip added for TLS1.3 :

```
#define SECURITY_PROTOCOL_TLSV13 0x00
securityInfo->bySecurityProtocol = SECURITY_PROTOCOL_TLSV13;
sChannelCred->grbitEnabledProtocols =SP_PROT_TLS1_3_CLIENT;
```

`status = pMyFunTab->**AcquireCredentialsHandleA**(NULL, UNISP_NAME_A, SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL, &sChannelCred, NULL, NULL, phCred, &ts);`

Return status = **SEC_E_ALGORITHM_MISMATCH**(0x80090331)

`**error details: Secure connection failed. An error occurred while trying to connect to the host, error code 0x80090331.     The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.**`

api link :

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acquirecredentialshandlea
> https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/SecAuthN/acquirecredentialshandle--schannel.md

---

***Tried the below change to fix the same:***

Windows version tested with:
windows 11 21h2 os build 22000.434

Registry Change: as suggested below link:
[how to enable TLS 1.3 in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072561/how-to-enable-tls-1-3-in-windows-10)

Any suggestion or a small sample of C++ code snipped is well appreciated,
as well as any advice which may help me to understand what is wrong with the client.

**FYI: I am not using CURL LIB.**

Thank you

Regards: Ajay Jaiswal

Comment: a [mre] would help

Comment: please try to focus the question on one specific issue. Asking if someone else has used it as well as asking for example code is offtopic. If you show your code it will be easier to help

Comment: Do you control both ends of the connection? What makes complete sense is that the receiving end doesn't support the correct version, and so the error you get, is just what it says it is

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same issue in Win11 but the same code below works in Win10. Please note TLS 1.3 has been enabled in the registry of my Win11.

```
     SCHANNEL_CRED SchannelCred;
     CredHandle hClientCreds;
     TimeStamp tsExpiry;
    
     PSecurityFunctionTable sspi = InitSecurityInterface();
    
     ZeroMemory(&SchannelCred, sizeof(SchannelCred));
     SchannelCred.dwVersion = SCHANNEL_CRED_VERSION;
     SchannelCred.grbitEnabledProtocols = SP_PROT_TLS1_3_CLIENT;
     SchannelCred.dwFlags |= SCH_CRED_MANUAL_CRED_VALIDATION | SCH_CRED_NO_DEFAULT_CREDS | SCH_USE_STRONG_CRYPTO;
    
     SECURITY_STATUS Status = sspi->AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL,
         (SEC_CHAR*)UNISP_NAME_A,
         SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,
         NULL,
         &SchannelCred,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         &hClientCreds,
         &tsExpiry);
```

Later, found it's required to use SCH_CREDENTIALS structure instead of SCHANNEL_CRED structure for TLS 1.3 in Win11.

Answer (score 2):

Gilles, did you try latest curl 7.81.0 on Win10 or Win11 with schannel as SSL backend? The following is what I saw.

```
curl -vI --tls-max 1.3 https://www.google.com
*   Trying 142.251.35.164:443...
* Connected to www.google.com (142.251.35.164) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: TLS 1.3 is not yet supported
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) schannel: TLS 1.3 is not yet supported
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a curl pull request with schannel tls 1.3 support

You can take a look at https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/7784

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I missed adding that I am not using CURL Lib.   If you could help without CURL, It would be great! Thank you