# Only enable TLS.1.3 in Web-Api hosting in Kestrel-Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kestrel, tls1.3

We are currently developing an ASP NET Core Web API hosted in a Kestrel Windows service. We want to enable TLS 1.3 only and disable all other SSL protocols.

The following code works. TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 are both enabled.

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsForDeveloper": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "SslProtocols": ["Tls12", "Tls13"]
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Subject": "localhost",
        "Store": "My",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "AllowInvalid": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

But if I change the code block to remove TLS1.2. Is the page no longer available.

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsForDeveloper": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "SslProtocols": ["Tls13"]
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Subject": "localhost",
        "Store": "My",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "AllowInvalid": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Postman I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone have any tips for me or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the lack of support for TLS 1.3 in the Windows versions we used. I was able to solve the problem with the following article.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210166/6092585