# net framework 4.8 + tls.13 = The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.8, tls1.3

Good day. Im updating net framework 4.8 wcf service with tls1.3 (third partiy will stop support tls12 at beginning 2024) and faced with " The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." exception during wcf call.

OS: Win 10 pro build 19045 (yeah, I know that win 10 supported tls13 in "experimental" mode), I manually enabled TLS13 via regedit
[image]

and forced my app use Tls13

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

But each wcf call throws exception above. According to [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) net framework 4.8 fully supported tls13.

Can I somehow fix this exception and successfully call wcf third party (with tls13) from net framework application?

**P.S.**
.net 6 application deployed on same machine can communicate with wcf third party without any issues (after adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13`) , so I believe this is issue in net 4.8

**P.S.S.**
updating to latest net framework 4.8.1 didnt helped

Comment: @shingo thanks for the comment. what did you tried to say by this article?

Comment: I think it's not a Framework issue. Did you try on W11?  
Force TLS on regedit will not make W10 support tls13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update local env up to Windows 11 and host to Windows Server 2022 solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though .NET 4.8 states that is supports TLS1.3 because it uses SChannel of Windows to do its work and according to this table here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

Native SChannel implementation on Windows 10 and Windows 10 Server version 1903 (May 2019 Update) and newer supports TLS 1.3.
[how to enable TLS 1.3 in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072561/how-to-enable-tls-1-3-in-windows-10)

I suggest you check out the documentation:

[If your app targets .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-net-framework-47-or-later-versions)

This sections show how to verify you're not using a specific TLS or SSL version.

If you really need to use TLS 1.3 on the server side, a far better option would be to use .NET 6 to begin with.

[Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675#issuecomment-678421120)

Comment: thanks for suggestion. "how to enable TLS 1.3 in windows 10" has incorrect link. I checked rest articles you posted but they gives no valuable information. Unfortunately updating domain from net framework 4.8 to net 6 is not an option

Comment: I re-edited the link.